# angularjs material radio button to default select

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am facing an issue in Angular material radio buttons when page loads any one of the option should be selected as default i am trying with `checked`and `aria-checked="true"` but it is not working

```
<div class = "row radio">
        <md-radio-group ng-model="searchFlight.myVar">
          <md-radio-button  class="md-primary fix-width" value="OneWay">One-way</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button  class="md-primary fix-width"  value="RoundTrip">Round Trip </md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button  class="md-primary fix-width"  value="MultyWay">Multi-Way + Hotal</md-radio-button>

        </md-radio-group>
    </div>
```

And i have conditional div's

```
<div class = "row Date" ng-switch="searchFlight.myVar">
            <div class = "col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class = "col-lg-11" ng-switch-default>
                  <div layout="column" class = "custom-date">
                    <label>Depart on</label>
                    <md-datepicker name="subDate" ng-model="searchFlight.submissionDate" md-placeholder="Pick a date" required ></md-datepicker>
                    <div class="validation-messages" ng-messages="searchFlight.subDate.$error">
                      <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>
                      <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "col-lg-11" ng-switch-when="RoundTrip">
                  <div layout="column" class = "custom-date">   
                    <label>Depart on</label>
                    <md-datepicker ng-model="searchFlight.submissionDate" md-placeholder="Pick a date"></md-datepicker>
                  </div>

                  <div layout="column" class = "custom-date">
                    <label>Return on</label>
                    <md-datepicker ng-model="searchFlight.submissionReturnDate" md-placeholder="Pick a date" required></md-datepicker>
                    <div class="validation-messages" ng-messages="myForm.dateField.$error">
                      <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>
                      <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

and in my controller i have given like

```
$scope.searchFlight = {
      myVar: 'OneWay'
    }
```

Any suggesions? Do i need to interact with controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the ng-model for the group,

```
 <md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1">

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      group1: 'OneWay'
    };
  }
]);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/GZsPdX?p=preview)**

Comment: HI Thanks for the solution. but in my case i have a conditional datepickers based on my selected radio button i think it is bloking from making it as default

Comment: check if you have same scope variable, also mark as answer if it had helped

Comment: Problem is this, you are using same scope variable for ng-switch change it to some else,

Comment: If i change the conditional functionality will not work right . Hear if i select one way it should show the default with single date picker if i select round trip it should hide the one way stricture and show round trip stricture. So can you please let me know what should e my approach?

Comment: There were few mistakes on ng-switch i have corrected it check here https://plnkr.co/edit/GZsPdX?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help. it is working absolutely fine in PLUNKER if i keep the same code in my project it is not working. :(

Comment: did you check the versions? there could be some dependency issues

Comment: i am using all updated versions of angular 1.5.5 and angular material of 1.1.0 . and i have not used much of  dependency only 'ngMaterial', 'ngAutocomplete','ui.router','ui.bootstrap' these as dependency in my app. is there any work around  this is how my code looks like https://plnkr.co/edit/sISR5Xk5Rihdozmtih9k?p=preview   Sorry it is not running in the tool for some reasons. can you tell me where i am going wrong?